# Is there a known way of making an API parameter signature dynamic in OOP?

Tags: java, oop

Without the need to define an overloaded method and constructor, I am studying Java by self, I was wandering if there is an Algorithm or trick that allows you change the number of parameter arguments dynamically to satisfy a general of programming which my require different types of data argument. For Example,

```
class Example{
public Example(){
}
/** the method bellow is not practical, but assume you wish to do something like this */
public String userDetails(Dynamic (either an int, a String_array, String or C), char append){
String[] fullName;                //define fullName
int age;                         //define age
char appends                    // define appends
if( num == age);               // assume it is age and return age,
if(fullName.equals(names[]);  // assume it is full name return full name list
if(.equals(char);            //assume it is an append of name
if (appends.equals(append); // it is an alien 
return null;
        }
```

A more breakdown of the code above should be like this

//Any of the data can be passed into this parameter because the parameter is dynamic and adjust to suit what it receives
public void userDetails(Dynamic (any of int, String[], String, char{ 
/*Normally if String is only accepted argument, and int is passed, and unmatched error occurs, if both string and int is accepted then only of the two is passed, same error occurs, The idea is to allow any of the type to be passed or maybe not even passed at all without us having to worry about catching exceptions*/
            }

The Idea is to pass Any kind of data to a method that is not overloaded and that method will automatically adjust to what ever data that is being passed to it. Conventionally if you need a String and Integer as an argument, you must define a String in the parameter respectively, but what if you need either a string or integer, Dynamic can intelligently accept any of the two.

NOTE: Dynamic itself is not a class, but a concept

As you can see that is a total gibberish, but for purpose of Explanation, is there anyway this can be implemented even not in this style Except Overloaded way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you give an example of how you'd like to *use* this method, assuming such a method could be created?

Comment: You could pass a Map with very flexible data. You could make some parameters "optional" by allowing `null` to mean "ignore".

Comment: You may be interested in the Visitor pattern.

Comment: @Thilo "optional" is the idea. But how would this affect the structure of the method, wont parameters stated non optional be given higher priority?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the ellipsis operator. See @jossef-harush's answer for details

Comment: It would be better if you tell us your main goal. What do you want to achieve with this in the big picture? This idea seems just to stem from misunderstanding of your domain/not enough programming knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

## You can hack it,

by signing your method like this:

```
Object dynamicFunction(Object ... params)
```

That will get you a generic way to control your arguments

**for instance**:

```
public static Object dynamicFunction(Object ... params){
    System.out.println(params.length);
    return null;
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    dynamicFunction();
    dynamicFunction(1,2,3, "34");
    dynamicFunction("hello", true, "world");
}
```

- **online example https://ideone.com/CG3uOY**

---

#### But wait!

Don't use that approach. **It's better give the methods different names** or to use overloading,

- it's more clear
- that's the standard in java
- enjoy the advantage of compilation and detecting bugs immediately

Comment: I'd even go a step further and say "don't use overloading, give the methods different names". Overloading also leads to errors, what with the complications introduced by autoboxing and dynamic type vs static dispatch.

Comment: note that with this method you need you will need a lot of explicit type checking in your code to use your data! Overloading is there for this purpose. Or you can also use a `Map<String, Object>` instead of a `Object ... objects` as input parameter. In this way at least you can use keys to deduce object type.

Comment: @Tommaso Pasini . Since I am studying, what Jossef says seems to be what I was looking for. I will try it an see what I can do with it. But I am a little concern about Object class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want a function with optional many parameters where any parameter is given (and the rest `null`) and it will return the value for the given parameter (e.g., age is given so return the user's age).

The OOP-way would be to create a class `User` with methods to access the age, name etc. Then, you would have a second class which knows all users (e.g., holds a `List` of all users) and offers *different* methods for accessing those information. The principle used here is *seperation of concern*.